# Add margins between items in the Ext.Panel

Tags: javascript, css, layout, extjs, extjs4

I have a Panel with two buttons that is used inside another panel. Right now it renders the buttons correctly but I'd like to add a margin between them. How to configure layout properly to get this ?

[image]

```
    return Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: 220,
        height: 35,
        border: false,
        collapsible: false,
        renderTo: renderTo,

        items : [    
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                scale: 'medium',
                text: this.exportButtonText,
                handler: function() {
                    var form = this.form.getForm();

                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        var values = form.getValues();
                        form.reset();

                        this.plugin.printSettings = values;

                        this.progressBar.show();
                        this.plugin.doPrint();
                    }
                },
                scope: this
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                scale: 'medium',
                text: this.cancelButtonText,
                handler: function() {
                    me.close();
                },
                scope: this 
            }                
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Or add this to left button definition:

```
{
   margin: '0 5px 0 0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in between them:

```
{
 xtype: 'tbspacer',
 flex: 1
}
```